# Multer not uploading files when I include logic in onFileUploadStart() - NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, file-upload, multer

## I'm trying to use multer to upload only image files with node

File's upload successfully with this:

```
app.use(multer({
  dest: __dirname + '/public/uploads/',
  onFileUploadData: function (file, data) {
    console.log(data.length + ' of ' + file.fieldname + ' arrived');
  },
  onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
    console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path);
  }
}));
```

But I want to limit it to images only and add some user authentication (user auth not implemented yet in the example below).

When I start the server with onFileUploadStart included, it'll log to the console that it uploaded, but when I check my uploads folder, nothing is there.

```
app.use(multer({
  dest: __dirname + '/public/uploads/',
  onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
    console.log(file.mimetype);
    if (file.mimetype !== 'image/png' || file.mimetype !== 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg') {
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log(file.fieldname + ' is starting ...');
    }
  },
  onFileUploadData: function (file, data) {
    console.log(data.length + ' of ' + file.fieldname + ' arrived');
  },
  onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
    console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path);
  }
}));
```

Comment: Well, what is `console.log(file.mimetype)` displaying?

Comment: When I upload png's it gives me `"image/png"`, when I upload jpegs, it'll sometimes give me `"image/jpg"` and other times it'll be `"image/jpeg"`. I tried checking the type with `console.log(typeof file.mimetype)` and I get a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your boolean logic.

This:

```
if (file.mimetype !== 'image/png' || file.mimetype !== 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg')
```

should instead be:

```
if (file.mimetype !== 'image/png' && file.mimetype !== 'image/jpg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg')
```

Comment: Hi, `app.use()` requires middleware functions now. how to handle the same code mentioned above in express 4 version